clock_nanosleep is giving out inconsistent latency during wakeup in rt system along with some spike of upto 1ms
I am new to rt c++ development and sorry if i am missing out on something basic.
I'm experiencing inconsistent latency behavior in a real-time system using clock_nanosleep for precise wakeups. The wakeup period is expected to be consistent with a 250µs interval, but the actual wakeup time fluctuates within a range of +/- 10µs and, in some cases, spikes up to 1ms. This is happening on a system running Linux kernel version 5.14.0-533.el9.x86_64+rt.
Here are the relevant details:
OS: Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-533.el9.x86_64+rt #1 SMP PREEMPT_RT (RT patches enabled)
Thread Priority: 99 (real-time priority)
Hardware: x86_64 architecture

The thread is created with the following code:
int thread_create_rt(std::thread &thandle, int stacksize, void *(*func)(void *), void *param)
{
    int ret;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sched_param schparam;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stacksize);
    
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(0, &cpuset); // Assigning to core 0
    pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    
    ret = pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, func, param);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    
    if (ret != 0) return 0;
    
    memset(&schparam, 0, sizeof(schparam));
    schparam.sched_priority = 99;
    ret = pthread_setschedparam(thread_id, SCHED_FIFO, &schparam);
    
    if (ret != 0) return 0;

    thandle = std::thread([thread_id]() {
        pthread_join(thread_id, nullptr); // Ensures the thread runs to completion
    });

    return 1; // Success
}


The thread loop looks like this:
while(1){
    while(i < 240000){
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startTime);
        if (i == 0) {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tm);
            std::cout << "Start ::" << tm.tv_sec << "." << tm.tv_nsec << "\n";
        }
        
        if (i == 240000 - 1) {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tm);
            std::cout << "End ::" << tm.tv_sec << "." << tm.tv_nsec << "\n";
        }
        
        i++;
        control_signal_log << startTime.tv_sec << "." << std::setw(9) << std::setfill('0') << startTime.tv_nsec << std::endl;
        
        next_wakeup_time_ = AddTimespecByNs(next_wakeup_time_, 250'000);
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &next_wakeup_time_, NULL);
    }
    
    usleep(1000);
}


Observations:
The expected wakeup period is 250 microseconds, but the actual wakeup times are inconsistent, sometimes deviating by +/- 10 microseconds.
In some cases, the wakeup latency spikes significantly, reaching up to 1ms or more.
This issue occurs on a system running the PREEMPT-RT patched Linux kernel with real-time priority set to 99.

enter image description here
where x-axis is in nanoseconds.
enter image description here
Tried for precise sleep and wake-up in clock_nanosleep in a rt system with high priority which is causing latency

You seem to mainly be benchmarking the performance of cout...?

No I want to benchmark clock_nanosleep wheter if it can wake up in 250 microseconds or not(reason i am not using cout is because i want to run a non blocking logger here).

What you want and what you are doing are not necessarily the same thing. If it wasn't already obvious, you can't have console I/O in the middle of benchmarking. In fact you shouldn't have anything from iostream at all present there.

ok, got it .Thank you for letting me know if not for console I/O then how about using fstream to log it in a file ?and I am really sorry,This is my first time trying to benchmark something so can you please help me out if I am missing out on something obvious.

File I/O takes even longer! The correct way to do it is to start the benchmarking clock just before clock_nanosleep and stop it just after it. Then you may report the result of that in any way you want, with cout or whatever.

And compile the code with optimizations enabled as well. Yeah I know I'm stating the obvious, but some 75% of all "huh strange benchmarking results" questions we get here on SO actually ran the code with optimizations disabled...
